# Dynamic Stretch to fit YouTube Video using API

Tags: php, html, css, youtube

I want to recreate this: [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/0a1d77e5baba3d70517c92dd1ae0f84c)

HTML

```
<header role="banner">
 <div id="wrapper-video">
<video poster="" autoplay loop>
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/156843/cut.mp4"           
    type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2">
</video>
</div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
section[role="banner"] {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 }

#wrapper-video {
 position: fixed;
 top: -50%;
 left: -50%;
 width: 200%;
 height: 200%;
 z-index: -100;
 }

#wrapper-video video {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto;
 min-width: 50%;
 min-height: 50%;
 }
```

...but replace the video with a YouTube video loaded via YouTube's API which loads the player into a DIV like this:

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

But as soon as I start to change the html the centering is off, even if I change the above to an image (as proof of concept) the centering is also off. What am I doing wrong here?

Does #wrapper-video video do something unexpected if I just change it to #wrapper-video2 and rename the DIV it was in?

Comment: Maybe this is better for you? https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/PZyMrd

Comment: @Miro: This works, but still breaks down when the screen goes super wide or super skinny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#player` will be replaced with an `iframe`. Here' how you would use that responsive code with the youtube API.

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '360',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
  });
}
```

```css
section[role="banner"] {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper-video {
  position: fixed;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  z-index: -100;
}

#wrapper-video video,
#wrapper-video iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  <div id="wrapper-video">
    <div id="player"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I am getting a completely black screen after trying this, but other aspects of the API (state change) are triggering so it appears that the video is playing, just not visible...

Comment: @Patrick you're saying you only see a black screen here? http://i.imgur.com/zXsTX31.png Loads the video and positions it per your CSS to me... If you want help, I'm going to need more context.

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing this: http://imgur.com/a/tGcoj I will work more on it - I appreciate the help though!

Comment: @Patrick I just checked this answer in a different browser and on another computer and it works fine...